# jQuery Time Since using HTML5 Time tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, html

I am looking to implement time since functionality using jQuery. Here are some example dates using the HTML5 time tag and microformat datetime.

```
    <p><time title="Wednesday, 20 April 2011 at 10:20 am" datetime="2011-04-20T10:20Z00" pubdate>20 April at 10:20 am</time></p>

    <p><time title="Tuesday, 19 April 2011 at 6:22 pm" datetime="2011-04-19T06:22Z00" pubdate>19 April at 6:22 pm</time></p>

    <p><time title="Sunday, 17 April 2011 at 3:18 pm" datetime="2011-04-17T15:13Z00" pubdate>17 April at 3:18 pm</time></p>

    <p><time title="Thursday, 2 December 2010 at 4:32 am" datetime="2010-12-02T00:32Z00" pubdate>2 December at 3:32 pm</time></p>
```

The idea is that the datetimes within the `<time>` tags will change to something like `2 minutes ago` or `Yesterday at 6:22 pm`. But for items that are older than a month then they will just stay the same as they are as I have left in a simple date e.g. `2 December at 3:32 pm` as a fallback should the user not have JavaScript enabled.

Can anyone help me to build something like this? I've been looking around on the web and found something by John Resig but it would like it to work with the new HTML5 tag and instead of grabbing the info for the title attribute get it from the datetime attribute. Also want it to be in the format I have specified, so instead of just saying Yesterday like his, it would say Yesterday at 6:22 pm. Thanks to all who can help.

Link to resig article: http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-pretty-date/

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at the [timeago](http://timeago.yarp.com/) plugin?

It might already do what you want and it supports the HTML5 `<time>` tag.

> HTML5 has a new time tag and timeago supports it too.

Comment: Looks great except I don't want it doing things like 1 year ago or 1 month ago only for dates within the same month and for the others just showing the date like `17 April at 3:18 pm` Also if the date is the day before I'd like to show `Yesterday at 3:32 pm` instead of just 1 day ago.

Comment: @Cameron - well the source is available on Github so you could easily fork it and make the changes you need. A quick look shows a few people who have done just that and their modifications will give you some pointers on what to change. https://github.com/rmm5t/jquery-timeago

Comment: I'm not familiar with Git so I'm not sure what I'm looking for in regards to the changes that will explain what I need to do.